# Attempting to create iterations with MATLAB (beginner)

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm very very new to Matlab and I tried to attempt at making a simple iteration script.
Basically all I wanted to do was plot:

```
1*sin(x)
2*sin(x)
3*sin(x)
...
4*sin(x)
```

And this is the program that I wrote:

```
function test1
x=1:0.1:10;
for k=1:1:5;
    y=k*sin(x);
    plot(x,y);
end % /for-loop
end % /test1
```

However, it only plots y=5*sin(x) or whatever the last number is...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the command `hold on` to make sure that the plot doesn't get erased each time you plot something new.

```
function test1
figure %# create a figure
hold on %# make sure the plot isn't overwritten
x=1:0.1:10;
%# if you want to use multiple colors
nPlots = 5; %# define n here so that you need to change it only once
color = hsv(nPlots); %# define a colormap
for k=1:nPlots; %# default step size is 1
    y=k*sin(x);
    plot(x,y,'Color',color(k,:));
end % /for-loop
end % /test1 - not necessary, btw.
```

**EDIT**

You can also do this without a loop, and plot a 2D array, as suggested by [@Ofri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596498/attempting-to-create-iterations-with-matlab-beginner/3596530#3596530):

```
function test1
figure
x = 1:0.1:10;
k = 1:5;
%# create the array to plot using a bit of linear algebra
plotData = sin(x)' * k; %'# every column is one k
plot(x,plotData)
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much, genius

Comment: @Amit: Glad it worked fine. I've expanded the solution a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to use the fact the plot can accept matrices, and treats them as several lines to plot together.

```
function test1
    figure %# create a figure
    x=1:0.1:10;
    for k=1:1:5;
        y(k,:)=k*sin(x); %# save the results in y, growing it by a row each iteration.
    end %# for-loop
    plot(x,y); %# plot all the lines together.
end %# test1
```

Comment: This way is almost favorable because it alternates the colors of the lines as well! simply wonderful.

Comment: על לא דבר. if you want to manually set the colors in a plot, you can add a third parameter plot(x,y,color). color should be 'r' for red, 'b' for blue, etc. so you can add this feature to Jonas' solution by defining an array of colors col = ['r','g','b','c','m'] and then add col(k) as a third parameter to the plot.

Comment: +1 for great points. I incorporated this into my solution as well, using a colormap instead. Also, I stole and adapted your idea of plotting an array.